# Windows audio service not starting win8.1

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, troubleshooting

I have a new PC and the sound has been working perfectly (the screen flickers occasionally, but that's not for this question).

The sound decided that it was going to stop working for whatever reason... :/

[image]

If I go into the Windows Services and try to enable "Windows Audio" (also named Audiosrc) I get the above error.  It's getting really annoying and spoiled my night of binging on Supernatural.  If I click the sound icon in the system tray then I get an error with troubleshooting saying "One or more audio service isn't running"

*If anyone knows how to fix this issue I would be grateful and if you need any further information just ask and I can append this post.*

Thanks,
Carty

Comment: try this: http://superuser.com/a/815861/174557

Comment: I tried using this solution but it didn't work... :/  What I have noticed is that the whole computer is playing up. For instance, if I go to open Control Panel it takes about 10 minutes to load, likewise with saving files or trying to open Windows Explorer (and my machine is definitely not crap)

Comment: check if the HDD is fine: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm relatively new to this forum so I don't know how best to reference this (as edit or new answer) so I'll put it here

I got my sound working!
I found [this link here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/windows-audio-cant-be-started-error-1740/d94003a0-aee9-44a0-9d0d-a8931fd45462) and it worked a charm for me as I use Windows 8.1 and have AVG 2014.

All it says is to open AVG 2014 and navigate to the 'Virus Vault' and then there was supposedly a virus with the location of `C:\Windows\System32\...` and all you do is **restore** that and **overwrite** the files; then you need to restart your PC.
Et voila!  That worked like a charm for me and I hope it works for everyone else.